# Press Enter or Esc to exit

Tags: conemu

I run a batch file with

```
conemu run.bat
```

When it ends, it pauses with a message

"Press Enter or Esc to exit..."

How do I disable this? If I wanted it to pause, then I would have called `pause`.

Comment: There is a setting for this under HamburgerMenu -> Setttings -> Integration -> Default Item -> Confirm Close.  Not only does the [help](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2660) indicate that this is what you want, it appears to dump a big pile of jack squat.  I gave up on ConEmu a long time ago because of bugs like the.. but even more because of the lag.

Comment: So, it's a bug. What's your alternative to conemu?

Comment: Win11 cmd is decent; I switched to it. I now realize how slow ConEmu was.

Comment: I used ConEmu in the first place since I had an issue with colors and tee with cmd. But I sorted it out (using python colorama and cygwin's script.exe).